# On renaming supertest.HTML to supertest.php generates 500 Error

Tags: php, permissions, 500-error

On Kittara.com/Supertest.PHP I have a basic HTML page (The home page is simply an image). But  I planned on putting PHP in it so I renamed it to .PHP On doing so it causes a 500 Internal Server error.

Error.log says:

```
[client 96.244.40.64] Premature end of script headers: home.PHP, referer: http://66.135.33.210/
[client 96.244.40.64] SoftException in Application.cpp:363: GID of script "/usr/local/apache/htdocs/home.PHP" is smaller than min_gid, referer: http://66.135.33.210/
```

Here is the code for Supertest.PHP:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">


<HTML>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body{
                width:99%;
                height:99%; 

            }
            #nexuss {
                margin-top:10%;
                margin-right:25%;
                margin-left: 42%;
                height:99%; 
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="nexuss"><img src="nexus s.png" alt="" width="258" height="516" /></div>
    </body>
</HTML>
```

Maybe it's because I don't have a .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

That's a [suexec](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/suexec) or [suphp](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/suphp) error.

The path `/usr/local/apache/htdocs/home.php` also indicates that the file is not owned by an ordinary user.

Solution: Change the script owner from `root` to an ordinary user account. Better yet, create a virtualhost documentroot elsewhere and chown it to an user.

If the error still persists, you must adapt the mentioned `min_gid` setting. It's often > 1000 or something.

Comment: I tried this, my user account owns apache and all files and sub directories

Comment: That's what it should *not* do. Create a new user with a higher gid/uid >1000, and test it with that.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: `addgroup --gid 5005 testgroup` and `adduser --gid 5005 --firstuid 7007 testuser`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are running PHP via the [suPHP tool](http://www.suphp.org/Home.html). One of the configuration options for suPHP is the minimum [GID](http://linux.die.net/man/8/groupadd) that a PHP script is allowed to run under. The GID of your scripts is below that minimum value.

You will have to either change the group ownership of the files or change the min_gid value in suphp.conf.